# Xdebug 3 + PHP-FPM + PhpStorm Stepping does not work

Tags: php, docker, nginx, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to configure Xdebug 3 using an image of PHP8.0:FPM and Nginx but PhpStorm does not stop on breakpoints.

In the logs it seems to connect, but does not stop.

```
[8] Log opened at 2022-05-29 23:54:51.960541
[8] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[8] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[8] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///app/public/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="8.0.19" protocol_version="1.0" appid="8"><engine version="3.1.4"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2022 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[8] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

[8] Log closed at 2022-05-29 23:54:52.382689
```

The extension is loaded:

| Feature | Enabled/Disabled |
| --- | --- |
| Development Helpers | ✘ disabled |
| Coverage | ✘ disabled |
| GC Stats | ✘ disabled |
| Profiler | ✘ disabled |
| Step Debugger | ✔ enabled |
| Tracing | ✘ disabled |

My Xdebug config files is:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log="var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.start_upon_error=yes
```

My Dockerfile for php-fpm :

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN pecl install xdebug

COPY conf.d/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

RUN echo clear_env = no >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

The `XDEBUG_MODE` variable is readable.

I add the server name as fastcgi param

```
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
```

docker-compose

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  # APP 
  php:
    build:
      context: .docker/php
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    networks:
      - default
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
    environment:
      XDEBUG_MODE: debug

  # NGINX SERVER
  nginx-user-service:
    build:
      context: .docker/nginx
    hostname: com.user-service
    ports:
      - 8010:80
    environment:
      PHP_FPM_HOST: php
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - default
      - cp-network
  
  # APP DATABASE
  mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      container_name: ${APP_NAME}-mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
        MYSQL_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      networks:
        - default
      ports:
        - 33065:3306
      expose:
        - 33065
networks:
  cp-network:
    external: 
      name: cp-network
  default: 
    name: user-services
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: What do you have on your host OS on TCP 9003 port? What's your host OS is? The Xdebug log response shows that there is some service on that port that knows how Xdebug works. I have seen such responses sent by php-fpm (quite common thing in Xdebug v2 times siince they both use the same `9000` port by default (that's why Xdebug v3 uses different `9003` port))

Comment: So .. use `netstat` or similar tool on your host OS and see what process/app will be using TCP 9003 port. It extremely unlikely to be PhpStorm (as it will do a much more lengthy conversation with Xdebug before telling "go away, I cannot/do not know how to server your request"). Also try `localhost:9003` in the browser (the same: on your host OS) and see what it will show. Right now it looks like you will have some web site there (possibly by mistake)

Comment: Just in case: 1) Xdebug is the one that connects from inside the container to the host OS (`host.docker.internal:9003`). 2) PhpStorm is the one that should be listening on 9003 port on the host OS end. Not php-fpm or another container etc. 3) Normally PhpStorm can detect that Xdebug port is already occupied by some another service .. but it works on Windows and Linux only AFAIK, on Mac it fails to detect this for some reason.

Comment: I'm using macOS 12.2.1. Regarding the port, PHPStorm is listening on 9003.     
```lsof -i -P -n | grep 9003                                                                                  
phpstorm  39224 martin.sanjuan   28u  IPv6 0x18637202aa3069ad      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9003 (LISTEN)```

Comment: So it should be good... unless (not sure at all tbh) it needs to be `0.0.0.0:9003` (so it listens on all interfaces). Not a Mac user so cannot check that. Anyway, if it's PhpStorm on 9003 then the weird thing here is the response -- it's not what PhpStorm typically responds (it has a much longer conversation). So check this: what response (Xdebug log) will show when PhpStorm is CLOSED. Will it be the same or different?

Comment: It seems that the connection or PHPStorm was stuck. I realize that always  PHPStorm was open, and started listening on 9000 and 9003, no matter if the option was off. 

I opened other projects, and some of those were listening for debugging connections. I stopped all, killed PHPStorm, and reopened it. But I got the same behavior.

I change the config to use port 9031, and once PHPStorm connects it to Xdebug, start closing and opening the connection with the debugging option. 

By the way, I configured PHPStorm to listen to an occupied port, and it detected it.

Comment: Odd. Does it work OK now, every time? If not .. what is your Docker Desktop version? *"By the way, I configured PHPStorm to listen to an occupied port, and it detected it."* Hmmm, the ticket is still opened: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29443 *"...and once PHPStorm connects it to Xdebug..."* Its Xdebug that connects to debug client (PhpStorm in this case) and not other way around.

Comment: Yes, it works OK now. Docker desktop 3.6.0 - PHPStorm 2021.2.3

Comment: Docker desktop 3.6.0 ?? Latest is 4.8.2 https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/ I though maybe you had 4.6/4.7 that has some issues with stacked connections... Anyway -- you said it works OK now, so the issue is solved. In such a case: please consider making an answer -- it can be useful to others in a similar situation.